# Has the language support for Garage_door Alexa Smart Home Skill feature been expanded?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-smart-home-skill

According to Alexa documentation currently Garage_Door feature is only available for English US locale. Has the language support been expanded to any other language?
I have read several questions regarding this topic and, as of march 2021, there does not seem to be any change, is there any chance this has been updated?
If it hasn´t, is there any way around is? If I have a garage door and I want it to suppot es-ES, it won´t get certified if I use Mode.controller?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are trying to use ModeController interface to control a garage door. Actually this interface is supported in es-ES:

https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smarthome/get-started-with-device-templates.html#garage-door

https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/device-apis/alexa-modecontroller.html

I hope this helps.